# Rename file while uploading in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple piece of code for uploading the files in php/mysql and it works well.

```
$target = "uploads/clients/";
  $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

  $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);

  //Writes the photo to the server
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
  {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO clients (img, `cname`) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($pic, "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['cname'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_thebest, $thebest);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $thebest) or die(mysql_error());
```

**Now what I want is to rename the filename if that filename already exists and then insert the renamed filename to the database**

Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$upload_dir = "uploads/clients/";
$target = $upload_dir . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
while(file_exists($target)){
    $new = time().rand();
    $target = $upload_dir . '_' . $new . '_' . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
}

// rest of the code now...
$pic= $new . ($_FILES['photo']['name']);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did some minor changes and I got the result

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by many ways.

**Method 1**

Check `file_exists()` before save to the server :

```
if (file_exists("../img/imageDirectory/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
   echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}
else
{
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  // Others insert statements here...
}
```

**Method 2**

Use `microtime()` to generate unique name for each file :

```
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = substr(microtime(), 2, 7) . '.' .end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $newfilename;
```

---

[mysql_*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) functions are deprecated. Do not use them any more.

Try to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 0):

Run a SELECT query checking to see if the name exists. If it does not, INSERT it. So, select all from your table where the name = your file name. If numrows > 0 you change the name.

Actually why don't you just use the auto increment value as the name and store whatever you want to call it in a separate column. Then you'll know each name will be different and you won't have crazy long urls or file names.

Answer (score 0):

First you must check table, that filename already  exists or not.

```
select * from client where cname="filename";
```

if filename exist, you can must change filename .